# Bind drop down list with Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm binding a Dictionary to a drop down list.

Say for example I have the following items in dictionary:

```
{"Test1", 123}, {"Test2", 321}
```

I'd like the drop down text to take the following format:

```
Test1 - Count: 123
Test2 - Count: 321
```

I was going along the following path with no luck:

```
MyDropDown.DataTextFormatString = string.Format("{0} - Count: {1}", Key, Value);
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a projection view by using LINQ on your dictionary and create an anonymous type to hold your custom formatting.

```
Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string, int>();
values.Add("First", 321);
values.Add("Second", 456);
values.Add("Third", 908);


var displayView = from display in values
                    select new { DisplayText = display.Key + " Count: " + display.Value };

DropDownList1.DataSource = displayView;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the DropDownList does support `DataTextFormatString` s that concat a String like you want to do it. As far as I know, you can only use format strings for numbers and dates. (For examples see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.aspx)

You can either do it the way ChristiaanV proposes (anonymous type), or you use your own `POCO class` (class only containing properties).
Be aware that using anonymous types have a limited scope. You can't usem them in a BusinessLayer-Assembly and have the GUI-Assembly use the result, because the ability of returning an anonymous type from a method are very limited.

I'd suggest you do something like this:

```
public class MyPOCO
{
  public int MyPrimaryKey {get;set;}
  public String DisplayString {get;set;}
}
```

Create a `List<MyPOCO>` in your code and bind it to the `DataSource` property.
Set the `DataValueField` to MyPrimaryKey and the `DataTextField` to DisplayString

If you are having problems with your databinding on **postbacks**, you can do the following:

1. Create a method that returns a  `List<MyPOCO>`
2. Create a ObjectDataSource and use the wizard to select the methods you created in 1.
3. Assign the ID of the ObjectDataSource to the `DataSourceID` of the DropDownList.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use string.Format in

> DataTextFormatString

Try the following code.

```
Dictionary<string, int> s = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        s.Add("Test1", 123);
        s.Add("Test2", 321);

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> temp in s)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0} - Count: {1}", temp.Key, temp.Value),temp.Value.ToString()));
        }
```