# Listbox formatting using DataTextField property

Tags: asp.net, listbox-control, datatextfield

I have a list box in my aspx page:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstTreatmentProvider" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="175px"
                                        Height="81" CssClass="SingleColumnlist" DataSourceID="dtsTreatmentProviders" DataTextField="FirstName" DataValueField="ServiceId"></asp:ListBox>
```

I am using this datasource for listbox:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsTreatmentProviders" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAllTreatmentProviders"
                        TypeName="Pc.PrecisionCare2.BLL.Administration.TreatmentProvider.TreatmentProviderBO"
                        SortParameterName="sortExpression"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

As you can see, I am using in list box, `DataTextField="FirstName"` because my datasource returns some data of treatment provider including first name, last name etc.

I want to have my list box as containing `First Name + Last Name` Can I do this somehow using DataTextField property?

PS: I do not want to do this in cs file. I want something in aspx.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `First Name + Last Name` in your SQL query, if you don't want to do it in code behind. e.g...

```
Select ([First Name] + [Last Name]) as [First Name],... from TableName
```

Comment: Im using LINQ Query and that is used at many other places so I don't want to change that.

Comment: I mentioned already that I don't want to do in cs file. But I think I have only these two options :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a Public property to your  *TreatmentProviderBO* like below

```
public String FullName
{
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName ;}
}
```

You can set the DataTextField to FullName.

If you can't edit the BO, I think you can use Extension Methods, though I'm not very sure whether you can give a method name to DataTextField.  You may try.

Answer (score 0):

Would this post be helpful for you?

[Bind drop down list with Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429392/bind-drop-down-list-with-dictionary/5429498#5429498)

I think you could use the anonymous type too.

Comment: I can't change my LINQ Query otherwise I know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the query as you are sticking with LINQ try the following one

```
  var aa = (from Varible in Collection select new { name = Varible.FirstName + Varible.LastName }).ToList();
```

Now set the DataTextField Property to "name". Hope it helps.